# The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended - Xammp - Version -7.3.8-0-VC15

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I updated Xampp version -  Latest version = 7.3.8-0-VC15 
I am getting these errors -

Error 1-

```
The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated. Find out why.
```

I clicked on to find out why but did not understand that -

Error 2 -

```
 mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'pma'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Error 3-

```
 Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
```

I tried many solutions but not solved.

Comment: That error is pretty obvious, isn't it? That user trying to connect without a password is denied access. Nothing we can do about that. You need to provide the correct password and/or account.

Comment: How to do this.

Comment: You really ask _us_ for the password to _your_ server? Emmmm......

Comment: What about this error -The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated. Find out why.

Comment: Well, did you look into that configuration? No? Why not?

Comment: Yes, I looked but not understand. I already mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

It's a mistake for missing some defaults table for default phpmydamin database. For solve this mistake you must to run following queries in ***phpmyadmin database***

I suggest you download and install `JetBrains DataGrip` and connect this software with your local database and run following query on it to fixing phpmyadmin problem. another way is if you are friendly with command line log in to mysql with command line and run queries.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_users` (
  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `usergroup` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`,`usergroup`)
) 
  COMMENT='Users and their assignments to user groups'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_usergroups` (
  `usergroup` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `tab` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `allowed` enum('Y','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
  PRIMARY KEY (`usergroup`,`tab`,`allowed`)
) 
  COMMENT='User groups with configured menu items'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pma_navigationhiding` (
  `username` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `item_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `item_type` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `db_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  `table_name` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`username`,`item_name`,`item_type`,`db_name`,`table_name`)
) 
  COMMENT='Hidden items of navigation tree'
  DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

Then add following code to **config.inc.php** file:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['users'] = 'pma_users';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['usergroups'] = 'pma_usergroups';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['navigationhiding'] = 'pma_navigationhiding';
```

Comment: But when I select phpmyadmin database ---The error occurring-  #1932 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__tracking' doesn't exist in engine     .

Comment: @VishalRana You must to do this work with command line. you can read following link to know how you can working with mysql with command line:https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/mysql/connect-to-mysql-from-the-command-line

Comment: I am unable to select the phpmyadmin database. How to fix it.

Comment: @VishalRana If you don't like command line you can use a software for managing mysql. for example you can use `JetBrains DataGrip` and fix phpmyadmin error

Comment: I don't get it. Please edit your answer and add steps or commands in your answer.

Comment: What is file path for query in JetBrains DataGrip like C:\xampp\mysql   and where to perform the query .

Comment: I have done all query and added code in config.inc.php  but the problem is not solved ... This is bad .     same errors    #1932 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__tracking' doesn't exist in engine   and above errors